# How can I loop over random numbers to get coordinates for my class?

Tags: python, class, for-loop, random, coordinates

I need a loop over all of my clans, which are instances of a class. Each clan needs to be assigned a position, a x and a y coordinate. Preferably as two lists or as a single tuple (but no idea how I specify that). This is how it works for the 1st clan. Afterwards I always have to check, if the position is already assigned. If so, you have to search for a new position until it is free.
I then coded my class like this:

```
width = 20
height = 20
no_of_clans = 50

import random

class clan:
    def __init__(self, index, position_list):
        self.index = index
        self.position_list = position_list
        
        def index(no_of_clans):
            return list(range(1, no_of_clans +1))
        
        def position_list(self):
            for i in range(1, no_of_clans +1):
                positions = ()
                if i ==1: #i can do it either like this
                    positions = [(random.randint(0, width)), (random.randint(0, height))]
                    positions.append(x,y)
                else: #or like this, I do not know, which one is better, both are running
                    x = (random.randint(0, width))
                    y = (random.randint(0, height))
                    #check if x and y not already used
                    #assert
                    positions.append(x,y)
            return positions


print(positions)
```

1. how can I assign positions randomly when also using 0.5 steps? I always get an error message.
2. I never get a list of my positions back, but I do not know what I did wrong.

I know those are probably fairly basic questions but I am quite new to python an already searched for 5h today and I really do ot know where to start anymore. I would be really happy if someon could help me. Thank you so much in advance <3

Comment: 1) Your class is named ``Clan`` not ``clan``, so ``clan()`` will not work. 2) your init method should be named ``__init__`` (your init method is missing ``__``) 3) the scope of ``positions`` is limited to ``position_list`` - and even then it only exists if you enter the loop. 4) The same loop exits after the first iteration because of the indetation of ``return``. 5) please only ask one question per question. 6) If your code raises an exception, please include the full error trace in your question

Comment: @MikeScotty thank you a lot! That already solved some of my problems :) But now I am trying to loop over the position_list, I always get `NameError: name 'positions' is not defined´ if I try to get my positions out and see if it works they way I wanted it to

Comment: @LisaMetzinger to print out the position you firstly need to create an Object from your class Clan() like so (obi = clan()) for this creation you need values for the class parameter index and position_list 
After that you can call your function position_list() with the obj Object from your class Clan  -> print(clan.position_list()) this will then return print out your postitions

Comment: @T1Berger then I should define my possible list of positions outside of my class and then define the asignment of positions in the class?

Comment: yeah, this would be more logical - give your Clan() Class a Variable position where you store the position of an initialized clan object. Then you could in a for range(no_of_clans) loop create a list of Clan() Object with a unique Index and Position through the index of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my original question in this post:
[Coordinates of the edges of a honeycomb grid in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70294413/coordinates-of-the-edges-of-a-honeycomb-grid-in-python?noredirect=1#comment124262783_70294413)

Will update if I am finished with the class-thing :)